# 検索ウィンドウをキーボードのショートカットで閉じたい

Tags: visual-studio

CTRL+F で検索ウィンドウが表示されますが、キーボードで逆に閉じることはできるんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

VisualStudioのコード編集などでの検索ウィンドウですか？
ESCキーを押したら消えませんか？

Comment: はい、検索ウィンドウです。
ありがとうございます!
escで消えました。再度CTRL+Fで消えたらな、と思いまして。